# Add styles as stylesheet with style loader

Tags: webpack

I am using Webpack's style loader like this:

```
...
output:{
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: '/public/'
},
module: {
    loaders: [
       {
           test: /\.scss$/,
           include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/styles'),
           loader: 'style!css!sass?includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/compass-mixins/lib')
       }
    ]
...
```

I add a `require` for the `scss` file of interest to my `main.js`:

```
require('./styles/main.scss');
```

This works, except the styles are injected as an embedded stylesheet. That's not ideal as it adds weight to the page and precludes caching.

Is there some way to have the styles output into an external file which can be referenced with a `<link>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin) has been designed to achieve this.